# do nothing in If inside swift

Tags: swift

I am wondering inside of a `if` statement, can I have something like Python `pass`?

```
var num = 10
num > 5 ? doSomethingIfTrue(): doSomethingIfFalse()
```

The above code will be alright if both true and false methods are supplied.
What if I only wanna to execute just the true method??
Such as:

```
num > 5 ? doSomethingIfTrue(): ***pass***
```

I am hoping to have something like a `pass` statement in swift so the program will just carry on if false is return. I have tried `continue` and `fallthrough` but I guess they are only used inside a loop statement.

Comment: The thing is that that is _not_ an `if` statement. So your question is strangely titled and strangely proposed.

Comment: The ternary operator should *not* be used for side effects.  It may be tempting, but it's terrible style, and will cause problems down the track.

Answer (score 12):

You could, in theory, say this:

```
var num = 10
num > 5 ? doSomethingIfTrue() : ()
```

That works because `()` is a void statement.

But I wouldn't do that! I would write it this way:

```
var num = 10
if num > 5 { doSomethingIfTrue() }
```

Yes, it's more characters, but that's Swift; you can't omit the curly braces from an if construct. And your ternary operator was the wrong operator to start with. As someone else has pointed out, it really is most appropriate for conditional assignment and similar.

Really, it's a matter of adapting yourself to the syntax, operators, and flow control of *this* language. Don't to try to make Swift be like Python; it won't be.

Comment: placing () does the job alright. Writing a single line if would be the best way to do it just that I am curious to see how this can be done in Swift.

Comment: If always safe to mention both cases if and else, rather than a single if condition with a positive case.

Comment: So `(error != nil) ? print(error!) : ()` is not something you want to see in production code?  ...however tempting

Comment: @hgale I am definitely writing it that way from now on!

Answer (score 1):

The `?:` conditional *operator* expects a value in each of its three operands, because it needs to give a value back. Say you have the hypothetical

```
a = b + ((c > 0) ? 1 : pass)
```

What would you expect the `+` to do if `c` was not positive?

For *statements*, use `if` as follows:

```
if num > 5 {
  doSomethingIfTrue()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answers that this is probably something best avoided, since the ternary operator's purpose is to evaluate to a value in both cases – you really just want an `if`.

However, if you really want to do it, you can match the void return type of `doSomethingIfTrue()` with `()`.

This isn’t generic across all possibilities though.  If `doSomethingIfTrue()` didn’t return void but instead returned an `Int`, it wouldn’t work.  You’d have to use `0` or something similar instead.

This will work (depending on your definition of work):

```
let pass: Any = ()

func doSomething() { }
func doSomethingElse() -> String  { return "a" }
func doSomethingNumeric() -> Int  { return 1 }

var num = 5
num > 5 ? doSomething() : pass
num > 5 ? doSomethingElse() : pass
num > 5 ? doSomethingNumeric() : pass
```

If you ever use the value returned by these expressions, they’ll be an `Any`.

Don’t use this  :-)

Comment: just updated with a terrible idea that would work across different types for the true expression...

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a ternary operator for an empty else in a ternary statement? It is much more complicated and inefficient. Try this:

```
var num = 10

if num > 5 {
    println("hi")
}
```

## or

```
var num = 10

num > 5 ? doSomethingIfTrue(): pass()
```

Create pass() and have it do nothing, or print that we did nothing.